# Where do you buy moleskin in Italy?

Tags: italy, shopping

When we were in Italy, we started to get blisters on our feet. We asked several pharmacies for moleskin (*fustagno* according to the translator app) but they all shook their head. It's too late for us but it could help future travelers. Where do you buy moleskin in Italy if not at a pharmacy?

Comment: I'd use "vescica" the italian translation for blisters and point to my feet and let the pharmacist direct me to the right product.

Comment: How about a store that sells camping or moutaineering equipment and supplies?

Comment: Max, I wish I had thought of that. I was fixed on the solution I knew that I did not consider there could be another way to fix the blister.

Comment: It may well be that the moleskin you asked for is not the name of the product in Italian. It might be for the skin of the animal, for the fabric or even for the (note) books that go by the name.

Comment: In Italy, *salvapelle* is used to prevent blisters by dancers, those playing sports, etc. Literally, it's *save skin.*

Comment: Giorgio, I entered "salvapelle" into the same app that incorrectly translated "moleskin." It translated into "Underwrap." The Italian way of describing the product makes more sense than the English word. It is an Underwrap between the skin and socks. Thanks for the explanation. Do Farmacias normally sell salvapelle?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find it in a farmacia; you could also explain *per vesciche sui piedi* ... for blisters on the feet or *per prevenire vesciche ai piedi* ... to prevent blisters on the feet

Comment: I would Google Image Search for a photo of moleskin on a foot, and show the picture to the pharmacist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Moleskin* is only a US brand name; the word literally means:

1. the skin of a mole used as fur.
2. a thick, strong cotton fabric with a shaved pile surface.

Its translation in Italian has little relation to what you wanted.

Always describe your problem, not the solution - *Blister* translates to *Bolla*, which would have enabled the guy to understand what you need.